# IIS 7 Fails to do anything

Tags: iis-7

I can access the administrator front end but:

1. http://localhost cannot find the page
2. Any asp.net apps cannot be located via a browser
3. I have reinstalled, if you call it that - did it via the server manager, but no such luck.

Help!

Comment: Have you checked your IIS logs?

Comment: This question should have been asked at ServerFault.com

Comment: That's actually a feature! :D (Sorry, I couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 0):

Double check your IIS binding to make sure that it allows port 80, (all unassigned) and no host header.  That will get http://localhost.  Check Event Viewer.  If there are any issues, it  should report there.

Also, try a specific page to rule out the default doc settings.  e.g. http://localhost/default.aspx.